# How to disable bootstrap nav-justified collapse for smaller devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, nav, justify

I am using bootstrap to justify a bunch of tabs to evenly fit the width of the parent element.
This is important to me.  However Bootstrap automatically collapses these for smaller devices, giving them 100% width, which I don't want.

How can I disable this function?

Simple Code:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot

Comment: @JamesMohler I am new to stackoverflow and do not yet have the privilege to upload photos, however screenshot might not be necessary.  http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs you'll read that the nav links are stacked for smaller devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a container with class col-xs-12 thus it will be stacked on very small displays. After all if you want it to be non-stacked in all displays just write a media query.

Look there for media queries:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

If you share more code then I can be more specific on answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it with the media query.nav-justified > li {display: table-cell;} @Gokhan

Comment: you"re welcome. Please accept my answer so that anyone looking for a solution to similar problem can see this

Comment: This doesn't fix it; it actually doesn't change the behavior at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add width:1% to make it stretch

```css
.nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 1%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers aren't correct. Bootstrap has a built-in simple way to do this, the same way it handles the collapse for the top menu.

1. Add the class `navbar-default` to the `nav` element. It will collapse without this class, but you won't have the little expand icon (the three horizontal lines that you click to expand).
2. Add the classes `navbar-collapse collapse` to the inner div which contains the links that should collapse.
3. Add  `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 </button>` before your div that should collapse.

This will come out rather messy trying to cut and paste my 3 steps above; what I did was literally copy and paste those sections from my working navbar at the top, then paste them in one by one. Those 3 elements are what you need, though: navbar-default, navbar-collapse, and the button.