# Bootstrap : prevent "nav-tabs nav-justified" from stacking on small screen

Tags: css, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using **Twitter Bootstrap 3** and I have a sidebar and tabs in it.

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="side-posts">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
          <li class=""><a href="#recent" data-toggle="tab"><span data-icon="&#xe048;"></span> Recent</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#top" data-toggle="tab"><span data-icon="&#xe0b0;"></span> Popular</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
        .....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When screen's width gets smaller the tabs stack on each other like this

[image]

Is it possible to keep the original look and prevent this change?

Comment: Just edited my answer, let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to write my own tabs style to get it work.

[image]

Here is a [live bootply](http://www.bootply.com/JHU2hv6zY4)

in case link got broken here is the css:

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
body{
    background-color: #f2f2f2; 
}
.container{
    width: 325px;  
}
.side-posts{
    margin-top:15px;
}
.post-tabs{
  padding:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.post-tabs li{
    display: inline;
}
.post-tabs a{
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    float:  left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
    transition:color 0.3s ease;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(47%, rgba(246,246,246,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(237,237,237,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0 );

    color:#3b5998;
}
.post-tabs a:hover{
    color:#e95c40;
}
.post-tabs li.active a{
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: #444444;
    z-index: 2;
}

.post-tabs li.active:first-child a {
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
    box-shadow: inset -3px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.post-tabs li.active:last-child a{
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.tab-content{
    height:400px;  
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: Since the referenced link could die, would you please add the relevant css to your answer? Thanks

Comment: Instead of re-writing the Bootstrap tab control which is a bit of overkill, I used @james answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032136/how-to-disable-stacking-of-bootstrap-justified-tabs-on-small-screens

Answer (score 1):

You can add `float:left;` and remove `float:none;` editing the mobile media query inside bootstrap like:

```
 @media (min-width: 768px){
    .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
        float: none;
        }
    }

@media (max-width: 768px){
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
    float: left;
    }
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/52VtD/7771/

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle of it with the images in the picture. Thanks

Comment: no need for jsfiddle, it is as simple as the code I posted, default bootstrap, no extras

Comment: It works for me...did u see the demo? What is the issue? It is like in the first picture if u try to resize the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me, even keeps the default styling for bootstrap justified nav-bar.**

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .nav-justified > li {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 1%;
  }
    .nav-justified > li > a  {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd !important;
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0 !important;
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
    .nav-justified > li.active > a  {
        border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;
  }

}
```